# How to add or remove an item from state array in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

I have state array and when user click on an item , item should be added to state array. I use type script, interface for data model.

This is the code I used

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  this.state.activeItemList: [...prevState.activeItemList, newItem]
}))
```

Interface

```
interface IState {     activeItemList?: IItem[] | null;  }
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check if the array wasn't null or undefined then you can add a new element to exists array otherwise create an array with newItem.

```
 this.setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        activeItemList: prevState.activeItemList ? [...prevState.activeItemList, newItem] : [newItem],
    }));
```

Comment: It seems like you are checking whether `prevState.activeItemList` exists or not, without checking whether it's an array or not. 

Better approach will be initiating `state = { activeItemList: [] }` which ensures it is an array initially, instead of making a check, right @kwdowik?

Comment: Of course, you can assign empty array to activeItemList on constructor as you wrote, but I assume typescript still will be jellying that activeItemList can be undefined or null. @DaniVijay

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly *a* correct way, yes, and I'd say it's probably the idiomatic way today. You're doing both of the important things:

1. You're using the callback version of `setState`, and
2. You're creating a new array, not modifying an existing on on the state.

Perfect!

You can also use `concat` rather than spread:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  this.state.activeItemList: prevState.activeItemList.concat(newItem)
}))
```

but again, your way is probably the idiomatic way in today's world. Also, if `newItem` were an array (e.g., `activeItemList` was intended as an array of arrays), `concat` would spread it, which wouldn't be good.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would write it as

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  activeItemList: [...prevState.activeItemList, newItem]
}))
```

With the current definition of `IState`, it means the exact same thing, but if `IState` ever changes, I'm prepare.  Plus, the code emphasizes that all it's doing is adding newItem and not erasing anything else.

Removing I would implement as:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  activeItemList: prevState.activeItemList.filter(item => item !== oldItem)
}))
```

Comment: Am am getting this error :

`Argument of type '(prevState: Readonly<IState>) => { activeItemList: (IItem | undefined)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IState | ((prevState: Readonly<IState>, props: Readonly<IProps>) => IState | Pick<IState, "activeItemList"> | null) | Pick<IState, "activeItemList"> | null'.`

Comment: Sorry, fixed some typos.